# Has the " Logic of relations" chapter disappeared from logic books ( since Russell's Principia)? ( Looking for modern references on this subject)

Tags: logic

In Russell's Principles Of Mathematics and Principia, there was a chapter called " Logic of relations".

I cannot find such a chapter in modern logic books.

Could a reference having this chapter be indicated?

Does " logic of relations" have interesting particularities (1) from a semantic point of view? (2) from a syntactic point of view?

In particular, are there special **natural deduction rules for relational statements**?

Comment: Roland Fraïssé, [Theory of relations (Elsevier, 2nd ed 2000)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ieshAQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Robin Hirsch & Ian Hodkinson, [Relation Algebras by Games (North Holland, 2002)](https://books.google.it/books?id=G2Woh63bbycC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroAllegranza. Thanks.

Comment: Roger Maddux, [Relation algebras (Elsevier, 2006)](https://books.google.it/books?id=fjFH1WvPG9AC).

Comment: Alfred Tarski was the founder of the "modern" calculus of relation; see Alfred Tarski, [On the Calculus of Relations (*JSL*, 1941)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1415/Databases/Tarski_1941.pdf).

Comment: @MauAllegranza. Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome :-)